# How to include Do loop inside the With statement?

Tags: matrix, function-construction

I wanted to create a matrix by following way:

```
NN = 3;

M[x_, J2_, J3_, a_]:=
  With[
    {d = (1. + J3)/2.,
     f = (1.+ Cos[a])/2.,
     g = (1. - Cos[a])/2.,
     h = -(J3 + Exp[I*x])/2., 
     hs = -(J3 + Exp[-I*x])/2.,
     t1 = Table[0., {i, 1, 8*NN}, {j, 1, 8*NN}],
     Do[t1[[i,i]] = 5., {i, 1,8*NN}],
     Do[t1[[i, i]] = d, {i, 1, 8*NN}]}],
     Do[
       {t1[[i, i + 1]] = f,
        t1[[i, i + 3]] = g,
        t1[[i + 1, i + 2]] = g,
        t1[[i + 2, i + 3]] = f},
       {i, 1, 8*NN-3, 4}]}, t1];

M[0., 1., 2., 0.] // MatrixForm
```

But it shows an error:

> With::lvws: Variable Do[t1[[i,i]]=5., {i, 1, 8}] in local variable specification {d = (1. + 2.)/2., f = (1. + Cos[0.])/2., g = (1. -Cos[0.])/2., h = -((2. + Exp[I 0.])/2.), hs = -((2. + Exp[-I 0.])/2.), t1  = Table[0., {i, 1, 8 NN}, {j, 1, 8 NN}], Do[t1[[i, i]] = 5., {i, 1, 8}]} requires a value.

Comment: You have now asked several questions on this site, but you still ignore our guidelines on formatting posts. This is annoying. Please read and comply with with our formatting guidelines. We expect people who frequently post on this site to submit properly formatted posts.

Comment: Sorry for not following the proper guidelines. From the next time I must keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to understand when to use the delimiter comma ( , ) and when to use the operator `CompoundExpression` ( ; ). Second you need to understand that `While` does not make assignments to variables, but makes substituitions based on what look like assignments. So `t1` in your code isn't a variable and can't be used as the first argument to `Part` in a `Set` expression. `Module` does create variables, so you can use it for making `t1` a local variable.

Putting these remarks into action, I rewrite your code as follows:

```
NN = 3;
M[x_, J2_, J3_, a_] :=
  With[
    {d = (1. + J3)/2.,
     f = (1. + Cos[a])/2.,
     g = (1. - Cos[a])/2.,
     h = -(J3 + Exp[I*x])/2.,
     hs = -(J3 + Exp[-I*x])/2.,
     n = 8 NN},
    Module[{t1},
      t1 = ConstantArray[0., {n, n}];
      Do[t1[[i, i]] = 5., {i, 1, n}];
      Do[t1[[i, i]] = d, {i, 1, n}];
      Do[
        t1[[i, i + 1]] = f;
        t1[[i, i + 3]] = g;
        t1[[i + 1, i + 2]] = g;
        t1[[i + 2, i + 3]] = f,
        {i, 1, n - 3, 4}];
      t1]]
M[0., 1., 2., 0.] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Note: your function doesn't use `J2`, so why to do have this argument?

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. Actually I have provided a small part of my full program. On the later part it includes all the arguments.

Comment: @atanu. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Since you do, please consider accepting it.